# Does the male and female always split evenly the genetic material given to their offspring?

Tags: genetics

Are there animals known to have a different percentage of splitting of genetic material, like the male give 75% and the female just 25%. I know that drone bees have only genetic material from their mothers, I would like to know if there are also instances in larger animals (mammals and reptiles).

If the answer is no, then do we know why it is always evenly split.